# Extract data from multidimentional array into 2 dims based on index

Tags: matlab, indexing

I have a huge (1000000x100x7) matrix and i need to create a (1000000x100x1) matrix based on an index vector (100x1) which holds 1 2 3 4 5 6 or 7 for each location.

I do not want to use loops

Comment: `table` is its own type in MATLAB and tables are always two dimensional. I believe you are just talking about matrices.

Comment: Questions on StackOverflow generally should contain a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35065590/edit) your question to ensure that the code in your question is **Minimal** (only the code necessary to reproduce), **Complete** (all of the code necessary to reproduce) and **Verifiable** (we should be able to reproduce the issue using only the code in your question, nothing less and nothing more).

Answer (score 3):

## The problem (I think)

First, let me try create a minimum working example that I think captures what you want to do. You have a matrix `A` and an index vector `index`:

```
A = rand(1000000, 100, 7);
index = randi(7, [100, 1]);
```

And you would like to do something like this:

```
[I,J,K] = size(A);
B = zeros(I,J);
for i=1:I
    for j=1:J
        B(i,j) = A(i,j,index(j));
    end
end
```

Only you'd like to do so without the loops.

## Linear indexing

One way to do this is by using linear indexing. This is kinda a tricky thing that depends on how the matrix is laid out in memory, and I'm gonna do a really terrible job explaining it, but you can also check out the documentation for the `sub2ind` and `ind2sub` functions.

Anyways, it means that given your (1,000,000 x 100 x 7) matrix stored in column-major format, you can refer to the same element in many different ways, i.e.:

```
A(i, j, k)
A(i, j + 100*(k-1))
A(i + 1000000*(j-1 + 100*(k-1)))
```

all refer to the same element of the matrix. Anyways, the punchline is:

```
linear_index = (1:J)' + J*(index-1);
B_noloop = A(:, linear_index);
```

And of course we should verify that this produces the same answer:

```
>> isequal(B, B_noloop)
ans =
     1
```

Yay!

## Performance vs. readability

So testing this on my computer, the nested loops took 5.37 seconds and the no-loop version took 0.29 seconds. However, it's kinda hard to tell what's going on in that code. Perhaps a more reasonable compromise would be:

```
B_oneloop = zeros(I,J);
for j=1:J
    B_oneloop(:,j) = A(:,j,index(j));
end
```

which vectorizes the longest dimension of the matrix and thus gets most of the way there (0.43 seconds), but maintains the readability of the original code.

Comment: Thanks, but i tried your example of referring to the same elements with different ways... it does not work, nor why should it? if the matrix is 1,000,000x100x7 why referring to an element outside of the total number of columns will get you to the next dim?

Comment: In memory, the elements of a matrix are laid out in a line. So the last element of the 1st column is followed by the first element of the 2nd column, etc. This is what I mean by linear indexing. Maybe this can explain it better than I could: (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511).

Comment: As far as the example not working, I realized I was missing a close parenthesis (oops!). Does it work for you now?